# Troubleshooting routing rule applied but not applied

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm sorry for the strange title. It's the best short description I know.

We have a series of routing rule for items in our incident table in Dynamics. Depending on the values in a couple of custom fields, an incident is routed to a particular queue (team). The routing hub goes through the decision list and stops upon the first match.

We have an incident that matched a particular rule. I look up that incident in routing diagnostics and plainly see that the 8th of about 30 rules was applied, with a nice, cheerful green checkmark as expected.

However, when I look at the actual incident, I see that the routing did not happen. Hence, applied but not applied.  The incident was not moved to the correct queue (team).  Many hundreds of others did route correctly, but this (rather important) incident did not.

My question: Is there a way to determine why an applied rule had no apparent effect on the incident?  Please let me know if there are any questions. This is a little new to me, and there may certainly be some basic thing I don't know about.